# foundation tab not working

Tags: html, tabs, zurb-foundation

I use Foundation 5.3 with Jade and express.

I created a tab component, pasted the code from Foundation Docs but it seems to be not working.

I included what css and js which I supposed is enough, however, only the active one in tabs can *display*, for others, when I click the title of tab, it doesn't display.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Profile | Login System</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="top-bar">
        <ul class="title-area">
            <li class="name">
                <h1><a href="/">Homepage</a></h1>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <section class="top-bar-section">
            <ul class="right">
                <li><a href="/profile" class="button success">12</a></li>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </nav>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-8 large-centered columns">
            <br> <br>
            <h1 class="text-center">Welcome to Login System!</h1>
            <h2 class="text-center">This is Profile Page</h2>
            <br>
            <hr>
            <br>
            <ul class="tabs" data-tab>
                <li class="tab-title active"><a href="#panel2-1">Tab 1</a></li>
                <li class="tab-title"><a href="#panel2-2">Tab 2</a></li>
                <li class="tab-title"><a href="#panel2-3">Tab 3</a></li>
                <li class="tab-title"><a href="#panel2-4">Tab 4</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tabs-content">
                <div class="content active" id="panel2-1">
                    <p>First panel content goes here...</p>
                </div>
                <div class="content" id="panel2-2">
                    <p>Second panel content goes here...</p>
                </div>
                <div class="content" id="panel2-3">
                    <p>Third panel content goes here...</p>
                </div>
                <div class="content" id="panel2-4">
                    <p>Fourth panel content goes here...</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="/js/foundation.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/js/vendor/modernizr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/js/foundation/foundation.tab.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).foundation();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

Emm... I have fixed this annoying problem.

I check out the template page downloaded from Foundation, and I just change the order of how I use `foundation.min.css foundation.min.js modernizr.js jquery.js` into the same order as the official one like the one below. And it works......

```
<!doctype html> <html class="no-js" lang="en">   <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Foundation | Welcome</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>   </head>   <body>

    <div class="row">
      <ul class="tabs" data-tab>
        <li class="tab-title active"><a href="#panel2-1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li class="tab-title"><a href="#panel2-2">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li class="tab-title"><a href="#panel2-3">Tab 3</a></li>
        <li class="tab-title"><a href="#panel2-4">Tab 4</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tabs-content">
        <div class="content active" id="panel2-1">
          <p>First panel content goes here...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="content" id="panel2-2">
          <p>Second panel content goes here...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="content" id="panel2-3">
          <p>Third panel content goes here...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="content" id="panel2-4">
          <p>Fourth panel content goes here...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).foundation();
    </script>   </body> </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've also faced such problem, and after some researches I've noticed that:

1. You don't need to load "js/foundation/foundation.tab.js"
2. The most strangest is that if you add type="javascript" attribute to foundation scripts then it doesn't work

Also as Zhen Zhang wrote before, do not mess with file orders! The order must be the same as wrote Zhen Zhang before

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem - not exactly the one described here, but I also had tabs in foundation not showing their content because the content was dynamic (a slider carousel). In case someone has the same problem here is concretetly what I did to fix it:

Assuming the HTML looks like

```
      <ul class="tabs" data-tabs id="my-tabs">
       <li class="tabs-title is-active"><a href="#my-tab1" aria-selected="true">MyTab1</a></li>
       <li class="tabs-title"><a href="#my-tab2">MyTab2</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tabs-content" data-tabs-content="my-tabs">
```

then just add the following javascript at the end of the body:

```
    $("#my-tabs").on('change.zf.tabs', function(event){
        $(window).resize();
    })
```